# MySQL Summary in new column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables which consist a set of data as below and i want to get the result as in the **RESULT** which will have a calculation in field **balance**:

I am stuck on the balance field, how do i get the balance running?

**tblIn**

```
in_date    | code    | in_qty  
-----------|---------|---------
2016-04-01 | aaa     | 100
2016-04-02 | aaa     | 100
2016-04-03 | aaa     | 200
2016-04-06 | aaa     | 400
```

**tblOut**

```
out_date   | code    | out_qty  
-----------|---------|---------
2016-04-02 | aaa     | 100
2016-04-08 | aaa     | 400
```

**RESULT**

```
date       | code    | in_qty   | out_qty  | balance
-----------|---------|----------|----------|---------
2016-04-01 | aaa     | 100      | 0        | 100
2016-04-02 | aaa     | 100      | 0        | 200
2016-04-02 | aaa     | 0        | 100      | 100
2016-04-03 | aaa     | 200      | 0        | 300
2016-04-06 | aaa     | 400      | 0        | 700
2016-04-08 | aaa     | 0        | 400      | 300
```

**QUERY** (thanks to @1000111)

```
SELECT 
t.*,
@prevBalance := (t.in_qty - t.out_qty) + IFNULL(@prevBalance,0) AS balance
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        in_date date,
        code,
        in_qty,
        0 AS out_qty
    FROM tblin

    UNION 

    SELECT 
        out_date,
        code,
        0,
        out_qty
    FROM tblout
) t , (SELECT @prevBalance := NULL) var
ORDER BY t.date;
```

This query will get the result as in **RESULT**, but what if i want this kind of result. MySQL will summary upto 2016-04-03 as single line and continue with detail for the next date.

**RESULT1**

```
date       | code    | in_qty   | out_qty  | balance
-----------|---------|----------|----------|---------
2016-04-03 | aaa     | 0        | 0        | 300
2016-04-06 | aaa     | 400      | 0        | 700
2016-04-08 | aaa     | 0        | 400      | 300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query.. i tested it with `2016-04-02` but feel free to change the one line that is commented to change date to any date you like

```
SELECT @startDate date,
       -- all this below to determine code since code has to come from somewhere
       -- for now we'll just select code of the latest date that is before
       -- or equal to @startDate
       (SELECT TCode.code FROM
          (SELECT code,in_date FROM tblin   WHERE in_date <= @startDate
           UNION ALL
           SELECT code,out_date FROM tblout WHERE out_date <= @startDate)TCode
         ORDER BY TCode.in_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) as Code,
        0,0,
        balance 
        FROM
        (SELECT @prevbalance :=(SELECT SUM(in_qty) FROM tblin,
-- Change the date in below line to any date you desire as @startDate is used throughout this whole query
                                (SELECT @startDate := DATE('2016-04-02'))TDATE WHERE in_date <= @startDate)-
                               (SELECT SUM(out_qty) FROM tblout WHERE out_date <= @startDate) as balance)T4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT T.*,@balance := @balance + (t.in_qty - t.out_qty) AS balance
   FROM 
    (SELECT in_date date,code,in_qty,0 AS out_qty FROM tblin WHERE in_date > @startDate
     UNION ALL
     SELECT out_date,    code,     0,     out_qty FROM tblout WHERE out_date > @startDate
    )T,(SELECT @balance:=@prevbalance)initial
   ORDER BY T.date ASC,T.in_qty DESC
  )T3;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3a6b/27)

**UPDATE** To prevent NULL just use IFNULL()

```
SELECT @startDate date,
       -- all this below to determine code since code has to come from somewhere
       -- for now we'll just select code of the latest date that is before
       -- or equal to @startDate
       (SELECT TCode.code FROM
          (SELECT code,in_date FROM tblin   WHERE in_date <= @startDate
           UNION ALL
           SELECT code,out_date FROM tblout WHERE out_date <= @startDate)TCode
         ORDER BY TCode.in_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) as Code,
        0,0,
        balance 
        FROM
        (SELECT @prevbalance :=IFNULL((SELECT SUM(in_qty) FROM tblin,
-- Change the date in below line to any date you desire as @startDate is used throughout this whole query
                                                               (SELECT @startDate := DATE('2016-03-02'))TDATE WHERE in_date <= @startDate)-
                                      (SELECT SUM(out_qty) FROM tblout WHERE out_date <= @startDate),0
                                     ) 
                               as balance
        )T4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT T.*,@balance := @balance + (t.in_qty - t.out_qty) AS balance
   FROM 
    (SELECT in_date date,code,in_qty,0 AS out_qty FROM tblin WHERE in_date > @startDate
     UNION ALL
     SELECT out_date,    code,     0,     out_qty FROM tblout WHERE out_date > @startDate
    )T,(SELECT @balance:=@prevbalance)initial
   ORDER BY T.date ASC,T.in_qty DESC
  )T3;
```

Comment: holy shit man, this is what i am looking for, kinda complex but would be better then run 2 separate queries.

Comment: anyways to prevent the null value if we select the date which is not less then the date in the table, eg 2016-03-01?

Comment: see 2nd query with IFNULL() to prevent NULL balances before less

Comment: Whenever you can run simpler queries...do it..a few simple queries are way easier to understand and maintain than one big complex one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
t.*,
@prevBalance := (t.in_qty - t.out_qty) + IFNULL(@prevBalance,0) AS balance
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        in_date in_date,
        Somedate out_date,
        code,
        in_qty,
        0 AS out_qty
    FROM tblin

    UNION 

    SELECT 
        somedate in_date,
        out_date out_date,
        code,
        0,
        out_qty
    FROM tblout
) t , (SELECT @prevBalance := NULL) var
ORDER BY t.date;
```

try using SOMEDATE(i mean any fixed date) same as you used "0" at both side.
it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've assume your date is ***2016-04-03***;)

```
SELECT
    @ROWNO:=@ROWNO+1 AS row_no,
    TMP1.date,
    TMP1.code,
    IF(@ROWNO=1,0,TMP1.in_qty)  AS in_qty,
    IF(@ROWNO=1,0,TMP1.out_qty) AS out_qty,
    TMP1.balance
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TMP.date,
            TMP.code,
            TMP.in_qty,
            TMP.out_qty,
            @BALANCE:=@BALANCE + TMP.BALANCE AS balance
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    out_date AS DATE,
                    code,
                    0 AS in_qty,
                    out_qty,
                    0-out_qty AS balance
                FROM
                    tblOut
                UNION
                SELECT
                    in_date AS DATE,
                    code,
                    in_qty,
                    0      AS out_qty,
                    in_qty AS balance
                FROM
                    tblIn) TMP,
            (SELECT @BALANCE:=0) B
        ORDER BY TMP.date) TMP1,
    (SELECT @ROWNO:=0) R
WHERE
    TMP1.date >= '2016-04-03'
ORDER BY
    TMP1.DATE
```

Comment: this works as long as the there is only one row for each date...this seems to fail for '2016-04-02'